# How to let laravel tinker make a request?

Tags: laravel

I want to visit my api in tinker just as below in PHPUnit

```
public function testBasicExample()
{
    // like that,visit my api and get a response
    $response = $this->json('POST', '/user', ['name' => 'Sally']);

    ...
}
```

But i don't know how to do that, I can just found [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan#introduction) in the doc about tinker.

Please Help

Thanks